# How to delete every other line in Vim?

Tags: vim

I would like to delete every other line from a Vim buffer, starting with the second one, i.e., lines 2, 4, 6, etc. For example, if the buffer’s contents is:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

then, after the desired line removal, it should become:

```
aaa
ccc
eee
```

Which Vim commands can be used to automate this operation?

Comment: You should be able to use a macro: http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2006/07/more_vim_save_time_with_macros_1.html

Comment: I like the wealth of answers to this one. Favoriting.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use a macro for this. Do the following.

- Start in command mode.
- Go to the beginning of the file by pressing `gg`.
- Press `qq`.
- Click arrow down and press `dd` after.
- Press `q`.
- Press `10000@q`

PS: To go to command mode just press Escape a couple of times.

Comment: Assuming your file is less than 20,000 line long of course :-)

Comment: +! to diablo, That's important otherwise you will go on deleting lines.

Comment: Actually you are wrong Michael. This works flawlessly as VI will stop running the macro as soon as it hits end of file. You can very easily try it out with the sample above.

Comment: rui, my bad. twice as bad, actually - I also misread paxdiablo's comment. But, honestly, I still strongly dislike your answer for being unnecarily "complex" wrt keystrokes and non-universal.

Comment: Well, like any macro you need to get it right the first time but after that you can apply to any file by just typing 10000@q. Either way I believe it's just a matter of tastes so I'm definitively not going to start a philosophical debate. :)

Comment: I prefer to use 'macro'. Using macro, you 'describe' how you would solve one particular task and let VIM repeat it for you. RUI, I would prefer to use 'j' instead of arrow key.

Comment: Lol a valid point SolutionYogi I did think about that (cursors might not work if VI isn't configured properly), it's just that I never really got used to using h,j,k,l (this might sound like heresy). :)

Comment: rui, definitely. I actually revoked my downvote which was based on my mistake, not taste diffrences. I couldn't revoke it before because you had to edit your answer to allow it ;-) And yes, if I were to do it your way I'd also use 'j'. After all arrow escape sequence is so huge :) (I wonder is there a difference while *executing* recorded macro, not recording it?)

Comment: Solution Yogi, actually, you can describe it in different ways. Like OP did - "delete every second row" (and this answer matches it perfectly) or "delete all even/odd rows". And it matters how you put it. That's why I think eloquence is one of the most important things for programmers. (and yes, I know I'm in danger now as I'm not writing my native language).

Comment: To run a macro reliably across all lines of a file regardless of length you can use the :norm command:- 1,$norm! @q  The norm runs normal mode commands from the command line and allows you to specify a line range which in this case is the entire file.

Comment: `:g/^/+d` from user http://stackoverflow.com/users/254635/ib (bellow) is more elegant way to solve this.

Comment: If you want to apply a macro to selected lines, you can use this after selecting the block you're interested at: norm!@q

Answer (score 310):

An elegant and efficient way to accomplish the task is to invoke the `:delete`
command (see `:help :d`) for the `+` line range (short for `.+1`) addressing
the line following the current one (see `:help {address}`), on every line
(see `:help /^`) using the `:global` command (see `:help :g`):

```
:g/^/+d
```

---

If the number of lines in the buffer is odd, the last run of the `:delete`
command issued in the `:g` loop raises an error because there is not a next line
for it to delete, but the resulting state of the buffer is still correct in
that case, so the error can be safely ignored. If so desired, the error
message can be suppressed from the get go using the `:silent` command:

```
:sil!g/^/+d
```

Comment: Why didn't this answer get more up-votes? This is so clean and simple. Alternatively you can delete the first line and run the above command to delete all of the odd lines.

Comment: @Usagi:  Thank you!  I feel the same way about it.  And yes, you are absolutely right, `:1d|g/^/+d` deletes the odd lines.

Comment: @Usagi The other answer was selected as the 'best answer' 2 years before his answer appeared. Also, although this is a more elegant solution, it could have been written in a more useful way (ie. there's no mention of what ^ does, while the macro is easy for anyone to understand).

Comment: Sorry, but without an explanation of how that command performs the desired behavior, I would not upvote it, and instead prefer the accepted answer, since I understand how it accomplishes the goal. It's the difference between giving a man a fish and teaching him how to fish.

Comment: I dunno, this answer made me go out and learn to fish with the :g command (that is, it made me google this page - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g ).

Comment: And if you hit him with a fish... But hey, the accepted answer doesn't explain either. I don't see any point in reproducing the global command doc. I had forgotten how to use the global command (despite being an ancient vi person) and found this page googling. Most helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution causes error `E16: invalid range` if the number of lines in the buffer is odd.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: It still works correctly in that case; you may ignore that error message. If you prefer, you can use the `:silent` command to suppress the error message: `:sil!g/^/+d`.

Comment: You don't need the `^`. An empty expression will still match every line. So just `:g//+d` will do the job.

Comment: @JohannesHoff: No, you do: when the `:g` command is given an empty pattern, it uses the last used pattern instead. Search for something that does not match every line (or anything at all), then run the `:g//` command right away, and see for yourself. (The `:s` Ex command, the Normal-mode `/` command, and even patterns within Ex command range addresses all behave the same way, too, by the way.)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had not realized! I guess I've just been "lucky" every time I've used an empty expression.

Answer (score 78):

We can use the `:normal` (or `:norm`) command to execute
the `j` and `dd` Normal-mode commands:

```
:%norm jdd
```

**Source:** the [Best of Vim Tips](http://zzapper.co.uk/vimtips.html) page by zzapper.

Comment: This answer doesn't get enough attention, possibly because of the lack of explanation both here and on the linked, messy, cheat sheet. the norm command runs the normal mode commands equivalent to the letters that follow it. So here it is running j to move down a 
line, and dd to delete it. This is generalizable to the Xth line by adding more 'j's in this case.

Comment: and the % is shorthand for 1,$ (execute the following command from line 1 to the end)

Comment: I'm interested in why `%norm ddj` doesn't work if you want to delete odd rows.

Answer (score 10):

```
:map ^o ddj^o
^o
```

Here ^ stand for CTRL.
Recursive macro to delete a line every two line. Choose well your first line and it's done.

Answer (score 8):

from [vim mail archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/vim@vim.org/msg11793.html):

```
:let i=1 | while i <= line('$') | if (i % 2) | exe i . "delete" | endif | let i += 1 | endwhile
```

(To be typed on one line on the vim command line, will delete row 1,3,5,7,...)

Comment: Then I'd prefer `!perl -ne 'print unless $. % 2'` :-)

Comment: And, Alex, I'd definitely prefer my solution to yours, but this one worth considering since this is the only sensible solution using only vim itself here.

Comment: The macro way is so much easier.

Comment: +1 because of the flexibility with `if (expression)` which also works for every third line etc.

Answer (score 6):

```
:%!awk -- '++c\%2'
```

alternatively

```
:%!awk -- 'c++\%2'
```

depending on which half you want to weed out.

Comment: Umm, why not use the existing `NR` variable?

Comment: Right. Because I forgot about it. ;-) But actually, the "proper" variant will be even longer with NR. And there would be no two *nice-looking* counterparts.

Comment: `:%!awk NR\%2` or `:%!awk 1-NR\%2`, as I posted in another comment.  That's hardly longer.

Comment: `1-NR` is longer than `c++`. Yes, I know it's one character. Like I said — the real reason is that I forgot about it. Anyway, looks like people do not appreciate the beauty of awk here.

Comment: And `NR` is shorter than `++c` :)

Comment: ;-) True, that makes total the same. But like I said - I like the fearful symmetry of counterparts.

Answer (score 5):

You can always pipe though a shell command, which means you can use any scripting language you like:

```
:%!perl -nle 'print if $. % 2'
```

(or use "unless" instead of "if", depending on which lines you want)

Comment: You don't need the `-l` switch to Perl... also, I'd say that `awk` is a little more widespread than Perl, though it's not really that much more these days, and can do this shorter: `:%!awk NR\%2`, or `:%!awk 1-NR\%2` for the other lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Vim's own search and substitute capabilities like so:
Put your cursor at the first line, and type in normal mode:

```
:.,/fff/s/\n.*\(\n.*\)/\1/g
```

- The `.,/fff/` is the range for the substitution. It means "from this line to the line that matches the regex `fff` (in this case, the last line).
- `s///` is the substitute command. It looks for a regex and replaces every occurrence of it with a string. The `g` at the end means to repeat the substitution as long as the regex keeps being found.
- The regex `\n.*\(\n.*\)` matches a newline, then a whole line (`.*` matches any number of characters except for a newline), then another newline and another line. The parentheses `\(` and `\)` cause the expression inside them to be recorded, so we can use it later using `\1`.
- `\1` inserts the grouped newline and the line after it back, because we don't want the next line gone too - we just want the substitution mechanism to pass by it so we don't delete it in the next replacement.

This way you can control the range in which you want the deletion to take place, and you don't have to use any external tool.

Comment: Or `$` instead of `/fff/`, for end-of-file regardless of the file's contents.

Answer (score 4):

To delete odd lines (1, 3, 5, …):

```
:%s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n/\2\r/g
```

To delete even lines (2, 4, 6, …):

```
:%s/\(.*\)\n.*\n/\1\r/g
```

Search for text (forms the first line) followed by a new line character and some  more text (forms the second line) followed by another new line character and replace the above with either first match (odd line) or second match (even line) followed by carriage return.

Answer (score 3):

As another approach you could also use python if your vim has support for it.

```
:py import vim; cb = vim.current.buffer; b = cb[:]; cb[:] = b[::2]
```

`b = cb[:]` temporarily copies all lines in the current buffer to `b`. `b[::2]` gets every second line from the buffer and assigns it to the whole current buffer `cb[:]`. The copy to `b` is necessary since buffer objects don't seem to support extended slice syntax.

This is probably not the "vim way", but could be easier to remember if you know python.

Answer (score 0):

## solution

you can try this in vim

```
:1,$-1g/^/+1d
```

## edit

I'll try to be more clear (two parts)

first part the selection range (`:from,to`) 
second part the action (`d` delete)

- the range if from first line to the last but one line (`:1,$-1`)
- globaly (`g`) delete (`+1d`) next line

you can try to move to the first line of your file and execute `:+1d` you will see the next line disappear

I know it is muddy, but it's vim and it works

Comment: Clear as mud. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Invoke sed:

```
:% !sed -e '2~2 d'

^^^^                  pipe file through a shell command
    ^^^^^^            the command is sed, and -e describes an expression as parameter
            ^^^^^     starting with the second line, delete every second line
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Responses to comments on another answer on this question (I can't comment because stack overflow requires reputation, it's so bad)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8334936/16603562

> We can use the `:normal` (or `:norm`) command to execute
> the `j` and `dd` Normal-mode commands:
>
> ```
> :%norm jdd
> ```
>
> **Source:** the [Best of Vim Tips](http://zzapper.co.uk/vimtips.html) page by zzapper.

---

> This answer doesn't get enough attention, possibly because of the lack of explanation both here and on the linked, messy, cheat sheet. the norm command runs the normal mode commands equivalent to the letters that follow it. So here it is running j to move down a line, and dd to delete it. This is generalizable to the Xth line by adding more 'j's in this case. –
> @imoatama
> May 13, 2014

This doesn't work (try it), *but* you can delete everything *but* the Xth line by adding more `dd`s (or `2dd`, replacing 2 with X-1.) Or using the top answer with `g`, `:g/^/+d2` (again replacing 2 with X-1.) Or just use a macro or sed, which also can do the original goal of deleting every Xth line for X>2.

As @Lambart said,

> the % is shorthand for 1,$ (execute the following command from line 1 to the end) –
> Lambart
> Jul 29, 2014

So if you do `%norm jjdd`, it will start the counter at line 1, then go to line 3 and delete it, but then it will go to line 2 and then go to line 4 and delete it, etc. This results deleting every odd line except the first line, not every third line.

---

> I'm interested in why %norm ddj doesn't work if you want to delete odd rows. –
> @Cyker
> Aug 19, 2018

This is confusing. My guess, based on lots of testing, is that the original `%norm jdd` works because when something in the command hits a failure, then it stops: if you're at the end and you do `jdd`, it does `j` and then stops because it can't go past the end. However, if you do `ddj`, it deletes first and it stops. But this doesn't stop the `%norm`, it only stops each line within the `%norm`.

Also, the counter goes from 1 to the original line number, it doesn't update it. (This makes sense because if it updated, you could do `:%norm p` and infinite loop.) And if the counter is past the last line of the current file, it goes to the last line. So it deletes all of the lines.

Therefore, to delete every odd line instead of even, you can do `%norm jkddj`. If it's at the end, it does nothing because `j` is at the beginning, but if not, it deletes the current line number. But it's easier to either just delete the first line: dd before running the command, or prepend d (`:d|%norm jdd`). It's the same number of characters, but it's more intuitive.

(btw this is tested on Neovim, it's probably the same as Vim but idk I didn't try)

Comment: rip, I can't ping people because names are probably not unique, I can change my name to "aaa" so yeah it's just a display name