# How to delete every other row, plus paste deleted results after selection?

Tags: vim

This is kind of a follow on to the [question about deleting every second line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946738/vim-how-to-delete-every-second-row).

How to do it in Vim:

**Before:**

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

(Say, it's a part of a visual selection.)

**After:**

```
aaa
ccc
eee
bbb
ddd
fff
```

How can I do this macro-style (delete every other line but store
deleted lines to buffer such that deleted lines are pasted in order)?

Also, if you could do this in a visual selection that would be really
handy (to parse a certain file)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** When the lines to reorder are the only ones present in the
buffer, one can use the command

```
:g/^/+m$
```

**2.** In general, when those lines are surrounded with other text,
one can either select the target range of lines to reorder and then run

```
:exe"'<,'>g/^/+m"line("'>")
```

or select all of the lines to reorder except for the first one of them
and then run

```
:'<,'>-g/^/+m'<-
```

instead.
In either case, the reordering is done efficiently and in a single run.

Comment: The second answer you have is really the most feature complete.

Answer (score 2):

1. Type `:let @e=''<CR>` to empty the `e` register (assuming you don't care about its previous content).
2. Place your cursor on `aaa`.
3. Type `qa` (or any other letter instead of `a`) to record your macro.
4. Type `j"Edd` to go down one line and delete it while appending it to the `e` register.
5. Type `q` to stop recording
6. Visually select the whole thing.
7. Apply the macro with `:'<,'>norm @a<CR>`, this will delete every other line.
8. Type `"ep`.

Comment: You officially satisfied that it is: a macro and uses visual selection, so credit is due here.

Comment: @KevinLee:  See also the Ex commands proposed in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362919/254635); they also work for visual selection.  Additionally, Ex commands are more universal, since it is easy to use them non-interactively (in mappings or scripts).  Not to mention that the commands I propose do not mangle the registers' contents.

Comment: For the record I agree with @ib.'s comment: I find his answer to be a more elegant and smarter solution for the problem at hand than mine (as is often the case).

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a macro for that.

We need a temporary register to put the results in, say register `e` (as [proposed by romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356743/520162)).

1. empty the register (the register must be empty since we're going to use the uppercase register name which means to append instead of overwrite)
   `:let @e=''`<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
2. visually select the area to work on (i.e. lines `aaa` through `fff`)
3. delete every second line and append that line to register `e`:
   `:g/^/+d E`
   Now, register `e` holds the deleted content
4. paste register `e` where you need it using `"ep`

---

**Discussion**

- we need to empty the register before using it since we're using the uppercase register name which means to append to the register (see section *Named registers* on [`:he registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers))
- type [`:he :global`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:global) go learn more about the incredibly powerful `:g` command (and it's not less useful friend [`:v`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:vglobal)
- 99% of the actual answer are already covered in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336154/520162) unfortunately not accepted but excellent answer to your referenced question. The only extension that you need is to accumulate the deleted lines instead of throwing them away (exactly: storing the last deleted line in the default register)

Comment: Yes, a straightforward extension of the linked command would work well.  However, there is an Ex command (well, I've constructed at least [two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362919/254635), in fact) that completely solves this reordering issue in a single run without additional interaction.  Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362919/254635) if interested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this variant is 'cleaner' than resorting to using a macro.

Comment: @KevinLee:  This answer just tries to extend my answer to the linked question.  To answer this question I've [constructed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362919/254635) a new command from scratch that is more "cleaner" than using this extension or a macro.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
:'<,'>g/^/+m$
```

It will move them to the end of file. Then you can move them back easily.

Comment: Thanks to both you and @eckes I just learned the `+` trick (`:h search-offset`). That's a good day starting!

Comment: You officially win vim golf here!  I'm not going to lie this is the one I would use the most- I assigned the check-mark to romainl only because I stated that I wanted it 'macro-style'

Comment: @KevinLee:  Actually, it does not:  This command solves the issue only partially; you should also count additional keystrokes necessary to move half of the text back to where it should be.  For a clean, single-run solution see the last command proposed in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362919/254635).