# Keep only the 1st line in every 4 lines and delete the other lines

Tags: vim

I have a file like the following

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
```

and I want it to be:

```
a
e
i
```

How to do it in vim?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946770/1084945), then modify for you (down, `3dd`, `q`), then run the macro.

Comment: This question is more complex than the other one. It should not have been marked as a duplicate. `:g/^/+1d3` is significantly different from `:g/^/+d`, and it was not explained well at all. To make things even more confusing and misleading, the `:g/^/+d` answer is incorrectly NOT marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with the following key sequence:

```
gg
qa
j
3dd
q
999@a
```

This is what the commands mean:

```
gg      # jump to the beginning of the file
qa      # start recording a macro in register "a"
j       # move down 1 line
3dd     # delete 3 lines (including the current one)
q       # stop recording the macro
999@a   # replay the macro from register "a"
```

If you have `sed` in your system (you are in Linux, Mac OS X, or using Git Bash in windows), then it's cleaner to do this instead:

```
:%!sed -ne 1~4p
```

This filters the content of the entire buffer, sending it to `sed` over a pipe, and then the `sed` command prints every 4th line of the input starting from line 1.

Comment: could you please explain why can't I use `:g/^/+4d`?

Comment: Not really :s The pattern `/^/` matches every line in the file, and then what I see happening is the first 4 lines are skipped, and then every 2nd lines are deleted, and we get an error `E16: Invalid range`. It seems that any number you put in there will only skip that many initial lines, and afterwards delete every second lines and I can't tell you why...

Comment: yes, would appreciate anybody to give a good answer to what you and I observed. `the first 4 lines are skipped, and then every 2nd lines are deleted, and we get an error E16: Invalid range. It seems that any number you put in there will only skip that many initial lines, and afterwards delete every second lines`

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336154/1743811) to another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1946738/1743811).

```
:g/^/+1 d3
```

(you don't need the spaces, I just added them for clarity)

- `/^/` matches any line.
- `:d` can take a numeric argument which specifies how many lines to delete including current line.

So the command translates to: for every line that comes after another line, delete 3 lines including the current line.

Another interpretation would be: for every line, delete the next 3 lines.