# How do I add a prefix to my vi editor in consecutive lines ?

Tags: linux, sed, editor, vi

My Input:

```
Test1.txt 
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

Expected Result should be

> chown user:user a
>
> chmod 755 a
>
> chown user:user b
>
> chmod 755 b
>
> chown user:user c
>
> chmod 755 c

Please suggest a best way to do it for 10k +lines in a single document.
Basically adding 2 different prefix commands for the same path (which is repeated twice one after another)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Vim visual block mode` may be you can consider. Because you have different prefix at the different line, so you must process each line with `sed`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If what you need is a vi command, why use sed tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file is like

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

You could use the vi command

```
:%s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/chown user:\1\rchmod 755 \2/g
```

if the entire file follows that format.

Grouping is used.
`\n` matches new line and `\r` inserts newline.

Or if the filename is included and your file is like

```
Test1.txt 
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

use

```
:2,$s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/chown user:\1\rchmod 755 \2/g
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to work with a list of unique paths, so start by removing every other line:

```
:g/^/+d
```

(taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8336154/9029328))

Then replace each line with the commands you want:

```
:%s/.*/chown user:user &\rchmod 755 &/

:%                                     run this command on the entire buffer:
  s                                    replace
   /.*/                                an entire line with
       chown user:user                 (literal "chown user:user ")
                       &               the entirety of the match
                        \r             newline
                          chmod 755    (literal "chmod 755 ")
                                    &  the entirety of the match again
                                     / (end the regex)
```

(`&` and `\r` are documented in `:help sub-replace-special`.)

Comment: Thanks AuxTaco for the answer