# Vim: How to delete 3rd Row and paste at end of file

Tags: vim

How to do it in Vim:

Before:

```
Text1
Text2
Digit1
Text3
Text4
Digit2
```

After:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4

0
1
```

There are nearly 19000 lines in similar pattern.Some digits are negative and some text also contains digits at the begining, which I am considering a part of text. 
I have refer to this stackoverflow post for deleting lines
[Vim: how to delete every second row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946738/vim-how-to-delete-every-second-row)

I want only the digit to be deleted and copied to the end of file.

Comment: you mean `:3m $-1`  ? see `:h :m`

Comment: I mean :3m $ not :3m $-1. It must work for every 3rd line as I have shown in examples.

Comment: All the same. But your example shows `$-1` or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually there are some digits which are negative as well. I donot have to mess with the order of digits, so that last digit has to be deleted and pasted at the end of file.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Your solution worked for me.Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines you do not want to move do not start with a digit or a minus sign, you can use:

```
:g/^[-\d]/m$
```

This moves each line that starts with a digit or a minus sign to the bottom of the file.

To match only lines that consist entirely of a number (positive, negative or zero) use:

```
:g/^-\=\d\d*$/m$
```

This assumes there is no leading or trailing whitespace in those lines, else you can use:

```
:g/^\s*-\=\d\d*\s*$/m$
```

Comment: Some are having negative digits as well. How to handle that?

Comment: just adapt the regex: `^-\{0,1\}\d`

Comment: @SatyamKumar: I have updated my answer to allow for negative digits.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden Your Solution was of great help to me. Thank You.